# Typo in "An error occured when uploading the image". occured -> occurred

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, uploader, spelling

When an image upload fails, there is a typo in the error message:

[image: Spelling error]

Zoomed-in version:

[image: Zoomed-in version]

Comment: Bump bump bump b (just realized that I need some context so this does not look like spam, the purpose was to bump the question in a way so people in the future will know that this was not fixed for a long time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for the report!  This has been fixed sitewide, along with another 21 other "*occurrences*" of the same misspelling.

Interestingly, this is one of [*the 100 most common misspellings*](https://www.englishclub.com/spelling/misspellings.htm) and not a single person in my house could spell it either.

Comment: I have [a list](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html) that is 25 times longer (sampled over 10 years), but it is missing many words. I wonder how and where they sampled the words. For instance, *ecstacy*, *copywrite*, and *gaurd* don't sound credible as "commonly misspelled" - more like the result of random sampling. It is also missing words like *[necessary](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#necessary)* and *[of course](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#of_course)*.

Comment: cont' - And *[recommend](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#recommend)*,  *[reusable](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#reusable)*, *[seem](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#seem)*, and *[similarly](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#similarly)*